# Element not visible, selenium chromedriver, java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to play around with Selenium and I am running in to a problem with it not being able to find anything.

My code looks like this:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Flows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/mn/Desktop/project/turv/src/main/chromedriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        String baseUrl = "http://anywhere.c3a.dk/";  
        driver.get(baseUrl);   

        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("placeholder");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("placeholder");

        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.js-login-button")).click();

        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());

        driver.close();    
    }
}
```

The issue arises when I try to interact with the website. The simple driver.getTitle() works fine, but i get an error when trying to access the login fields. I have tried with `By.name` and `By.cssSelector`.But both give the same result. I am using the Chrome browser plugin so record some things and then I try to apply what it says to my code, but I get the following error when I run this:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011) on port 31943
Only local connections are allowed.
May 07, 2018 1:06:18 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.139)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552518 (183d19265345f54ce39cbb94cf81ba5f15905011),platform=Mac OS X 10.13.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.11.0', revision: 'e59cfb3', time: '2018-03-11T20:26:55.152Z'
System info: host: 'cetreas-MBP', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:c9e:2c67:1d27:4e0b%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.13.3', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.38.552518 (183d19265345f5..., userDataDir: /var/folders/s7/lv2wt4t15cn...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: MAC, platformName: MAC, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: , unhandledPromptBehavior: , version: 66.0.3359.139, webStorageEnabled: true}
Session ID: 6d1cb5352073e7f1071830edf5b40106
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:545)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:279)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:83)
    at com.cetrea.flows.Flows.main(Flows.java:19)
```

I don't think that the `driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();` is necessary at all, was just something I tried because it couldn't find the other one.

Comment: Post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely WebDriver try to access the element before it gets visible. We need to wait for sometime so it get visible.

Try:

```
driver.get("http://anywhere.c3a.dk/");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("username"))).sendKeys("placeholder");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("placeholder");
```

Comment: Yes -- it looks like your finding the element in your template (which is not visible) rather than the one which Javascript has modified.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.button.js-login-button")).click();
```

this

```
driver.findElement(By.className("button js-login-button")).click();
```

Comment: `By.className()` won't work here because you are providing two class names. It will give you an error, "Compound class names not permitted". Changing the locator type won't affect the visibility of the element. The element was found with the current locator it's just not visible.